# popping out a particular value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So am working on a mini web project whereby the aim of the website is to create notes and these notes have actually been added to an array in JavaScript. But the issue is that am trying to delete a particular note from the array, I tried using loops to iterate through the array and finally pop out that particular value in the array but it still didn't work.

I tried passing in the index of that particular value I wanted to delete into the pop function but it didn't work.

Comment: You forgot to post (as opposed to tersely describe) your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element from an array. See the dupe.